# Order List in same order as another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of MyFirstObject called AList. MyFirstObject class has two properties: ID, Name

I have another list of MySecondObject called BList. MySecondObject only has a property:ID

**AList is ordered by its ID property.  BList is randomly ordered and not by its ID property. We want to achieve the order of BList in AList.**

(Apologies for the typo)

E.g.

```
AList = [object ID = 1, object ID = 4, object ID = 5]
BList = [object ID = 4, object ID = 1, object ID = 5]
```

The number of elements in AList and BList are equal.

I want to ensure that all of the items in AList are ordered in same order as they are ordered in BList.

Can you please suggest a way?

Regards

Comment: You need to clarify. Your question already states that AList is ordered by its ID property and that BList is ordered by its ID property. So aren't they already ordered the same?

Comment: could you please provide expected output?

Comment: I don't understand. If AList is ordered by ID, and AList's ordering is the same as BList's ordering, then BList is also ordered by ID. So sort both lists by ID?

Comment: Apologies. Corrected question

Answer (score -1):

Sorting both list on Id using Linq:

```
AList.OrderBy(o => o.ID);
BList.OrderBy(o => o.ID);
```

Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: Yeah - if it's not this, I don't get what all the confusing question details are on about